# Need to Activate a textbox right after its creation without calling its name

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I have the following two codes. First one creates a text box. Then the second one selects it for further operation. Problem is that the second code calls it by name. I want it to select it automatically as it has just been created by the code preceding it.

Code-1

'''

```
If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
    With Selection
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox _
          msoTextOrientationHorizontal, .Left, _
          .Top, .Width, .Height
    End With
End If
```

Code-2

```
Cells.Select
Range("C5").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox 18")).Select
```

As you can see the code only works if I give the name of he text box. In continuation with previous code how can i know the name of the text box.

P.S. Significant effort has already been put in making the larger code for which this question is just a subset

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Shapes.AddTextbox reurns the just-added shape, so you can use that.

```
Dim shp
With Selection
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, .Left, _           
                                           .Top, .Width, .Height)
End With

shp.select
```